# Error while adding foreign key to composite key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, composite-key

I have two table in sql server:

First table `Message_Child` has a composite primary key (MessageId, ChildId)

```
Message_Child (MessageId, ChildId, Date)
```

Second table should contain a foreign key to `Message_Child` table, so I created two columns: MessageId and ChildId.

```
Request (RequestId, MessageId, ChildId, type)
```

And I created the constraint as follow:

```
Alter table Request
ADD FOREIGN KEY (MessageId, ChildId) REFERENCES Message_Child(MessageId, ChildId);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

**There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Message_Child' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_*Request*_534D60F1'.**

**Edit**
Adding the code:

Message_Child table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Message_Child](
[ChildId] [int] NOT NULL,
[MessageId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Message_Child] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ChildId] ASC,
[MessageId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Message_Child]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT          [FK_Message_Child_Child_ChildId] FOREIGN KEY([ChildId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Child] ([ChildId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Message_Child] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Message_Child_Child_ChildId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Message_Child]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT     [FK_Message_Child_Message_MessageId] FOREIGN KEY([MessageId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Message] ([MessageId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Message_Child] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Message_Child_Message_MessageId]
GO
```

RequestQueue table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RequestQueue](
[RequestQueueId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PIN] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[MessageId] [int] NULL,
[ChildId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RequestQueue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[RequestQueueId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RequestQueue]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT   [FK_RequestQueue_MessageChildId] FOREIGN KEY([RequestQueueId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[RequestQueue] ([RequestQueueId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RequestQueue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RequestQueue_MessageChildId]
GO
```

And then I added this:

```
Alter table [DayCareDB].[dbo].[RequestQueue]
ADD FOREIGN KEY (MessageId, ChildId) REFERENCES [DayCareDB].[dbo].[Message_Child](MessageId, ChildId);
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. You can't have a 2 column foreign key referencing a 3 column composite primary key.

Comment: No the composite key is composed of two columns. See the second line. Date is not in the composite key.

Comment: Whoops, misread your table structure as your key.

Comment: Yes they are all int. So the logic is fine, right?

Comment: And is there a primary key `(MessageId, ChildId)` in `Message_Child`? Show us the code you used.

Comment: Can you post the *actual* table structure (script to.. create table).

Comment: The error message is clear: "There is no primary key or unique constraint on `Message_Child(MessageId, ChildId)`"

Comment: You have defined the PK in reverse column order than the FK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Key order matters here.  You need to use `(ChildID, MessageID)` **IN THAT ORDER** since that is the key order in your primary key definition.

```
Alter table [DayCareDB].[dbo].[RequestQueue]
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ChildId, MessageId) 
REFERENCES [DayCareDB].[dbo].[Message_Child](ChildId, MessageId);
```